# Grunt serve:dist works as exected, but when run under forever using a script, my app fails subtly -- WHY?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, forever

For my project running grunt serve:dist outputs:

```
Running "serve:dist" (serve) task

Running "env:all" (env) task

Running "env:prod" (env) task

Running "express:prod" (express) task
Starting background Express server
Express server listening on 9000, in production mode

Running "wait" task
>> Waiting for server reload...
register called. count:0
register called. count:0
register called. count:0
register called. count:0
[undefined:undefined] CONNECTED
GET /api/listOfLists/ 304 245ms
GET /api/tasks/ 304 267ms
GET /api/lists/ 304 240ms
Done waiting!

Running "open:server" (open) task

Running "express-keepalive" task
```

which naturally displays the expected comments from the Gruntfile.js.  (NOTE: I have modified the Grunfile so that the build step is not executed unless explicitly invoked.)

The strangeness occurs when I run a script with:

```
export NODE_ENV='production'
export port=9000
forever start dist/server/app.js
```

Which I believe duplicates (for the most part) what grunt serve:dist does.  So far so good. When I am already logged into my application, I don't see any immediate difference in my application and all looks fine. And the log file from .forever shows (as expected, since the user is already logged in):

```
GET /api/lists/ 304 48ms
GET /api/listOfLists/ 304 51ms
register called. count:1
register called. count:1
register called. count:1
register called. count:1
[undefined:undefined] CONNECTED
GET /api/listOfLists/ 304 102ms
GET /api/tasks/ 304 105ms
GET /api/lists/ 304 20ms
```

HOWEVER, as soon as I logout and attempt to login again, using passport, I see:

In the browser console:

```
Consider using 'dppx' units, as in CSS 'dpi' means dots-per-CSS-inch, not dots-per-physical-inch, so does not correspond to the actual 'dpi' of a screen. In media query expression: only screen and (min-resolution: 192dpi)
```

And the login fails in the callback from Google:

```
401. That’s an error.

Error: invalid_client

The OAuth client was not found.

Request Details
scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
response_type=code
redirect_uri=https://example.com/auth/google/callback
client_id=id
That’s all we know.
```

But the Request details are correct and expected. Even stranger, if I login using just the user name and password (which uses in passport the Local transport) the login works correctly and everything runs as expected.  It is ONLY when I return in the callback from Google that things fail.

So the question is: **What is the difference between grunt serve:dist and when this script runs under forever?**  Clearly something the Grunfile.js and grunt does is different, but for the life of me, I don't yet see it!

I am certain that someone else has already seen this.  If so, please help if you can! Thanks.

The Gruntfile.js is (in case that is needed - as generated by yo angular-fullstack)  My guess is that this is somehow related to timing, etc.

```
// Generated on 2015-02-27 using generator-angular-fullstack 2.0.13
'use strict';

module.exports = function (grunt) {
  var localConfig;
  try {
    localConfig = require('./server/config/local.env');
  } catch(e) {
    localConfig = {};
  }

  // Load grunt tasks automatically, when needed
  require('jit-grunt')(grunt, {
    express: 'grunt-express-server',
    useminPrepare: 'grunt-usemin',
    ngtemplates: 'grunt-angular-templates',
    cdnify: 'grunt-google-cdn',
    protractor: 'grunt-protractor-runner',
    injector: 'grunt-asset-injector',
    buildcontrol: 'grunt-build-control'
  });

  // Time how long tasks take. Can help when optimizing build times
  require('time-grunt')(grunt);

  // Define the configuration for all the tasks
  grunt.initConfig({

    // Project settings
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    yeoman: {
      // configurable paths
      client: require('./bower.json').appPath || 'client',
      dist: 'dist'
    },
    express: {
      options: {
        port: process.env.PORT || 9000
      },
      dev: {
        options: {
          script: 'server/app.js',
          debug: true
        }
      },
      prod: {
        options: {
          script: 'dist/server/app.js'
        }
      }
    },
    open: {
      server: {
        url: 'http://localhost:<%= express.options.port %>'
      }
    },
    watch: {
      injectJS: {
        files: [
          '<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components}/**/*.js',
          '!<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components}/**/*.spec.js',
          '!<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components}/**/*.mock.js',
          '!<%= yeoman.client %>/app/app.js'],
        tasks: ['injector:scripts']
      },
      injectCss: {
        files: [
          '<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components}/**/*.css'
        ],
        tasks: ['injector:css']
      },
      mochaTest: {
        files: ['server/**/*.spec.js'],
        tasks: ['env:test', 'mochaTest']
      },
      jsTest: {
        files: [
          '<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components}/**/*.spec.js',
          '<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components}/**/*.mock.js'
        ],
        tasks: ['newer:jshint:all', 'karma']
      },
      injectSass: {
        files: [
          '<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components}/**/*.{scss,sass}'],
        tasks: ['injector:sass']
      },
      sass: {
        files: [
          '<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components}/**/*.{scss,sass}'],
        tasks: ['sass', 'autoprefixer']
      },
      gruntfile: {
        files: ['Gruntfile.js']
      },
      livereload: {
        files: [
          '{.tmp,<%= yeoman.client %>}/{app,components}/**/*.css',
          '{.tmp,<%= yeoman.client %>}/{app,components}/**/*.html',
          '{.tmp,<%= yeoman.client %>}/{app,components}/**/*.js',
          '!{.tmp,<%= yeoman.client %>}{app,components}/**/*.spec.js',
          '!{.tmp,<%= yeoman.client %>}/{app,components}/**/*.mock.js',
          '<%= yeoman.client %>/assets/images/{,*//*}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'
        ],
        options: {
          livereload: true
        }
      },
      express: {
        files: [
          'server/**/*.{js,json}'
        ],
        tasks: ['express:dev', 'wait'],
        options: {
          livereload: true,
          nospawn: true //Without this option specified express won't be reloaded
        }
      }
    },

    // Make sure code styles are up to par and there are no obvious mistakes
    jshint: {
      options: {
        jshintrc: '<%= yeoman.client %>/.jshintrc',
        reporter: require('jshint-stylish'),
          "jasmine": true
      },
      server: {
        options: {
          jshintrc: 'server/.jshintrc',
          "jasmine": true
        },
        src: [
          'server/**/*.js',
          '!server/**/*.spec.js'
        ]
      },
      serverTest: {
        options: {
          jshintrc: 'server/.jshintrc-spec',
          "jasmine": true
        },
        src: ['server/**/*.spec.js']
      },
      all: [
        '<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components}/**/*.js',
        '!<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components}/**/*.spec.js',
        '!<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components}/**/*.mock.js'
      ],
      test: {
        src: [
          '<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components}/**/*.spec.js',
          '<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components}/**/*.mock.js'
        ]
      }
    },

    // Empties folders to start fresh
    clean: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          dot: true,
          src: [
            '.tmp',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/*',
            '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/.git*',
            '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/.openshift',
            '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/Procfile'
          ]
        }]
      },
      server: '.tmp'
    },

    // Add vendor prefixed styles
    autoprefixer: {
      options: {
        browsers: ['last 1 version']
      },
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/',
          src: '{,*/}*.css',
          dest: '.tmp/'
        }]
      }
    },

    // Debugging with node inspector
    'node-inspector': {
      custom: {
        options: {
          'web-host': 'localhost'
        }
      }
    },

    // Use nodemon to run server in debug mode with an initial breakpoint
    nodemon: {
      debug: {
        script: 'server/app.js',
        options: {
          nodeArgs: ['--debug-brk'],
          env: {
            PORT: process.env.PORT || 9000
          },
          callback: function (nodemon) {
            nodemon.on('log', function (event) {
              console.log(event.colour);
            });

            // opens browser on initial server start
            nodemon.on('config:update', function () {
              setTimeout(function () {
                require('open')('http://localhost:8080/debug?port=5858');
              }, 500);
            });
          }
        }
      }
    },

    // Automatically inject Bower components into the app
    wiredep: {
      target: {
        src: '<%= yeoman.client %>/index.html',
        ignorePath: '<%= yeoman.client %>/',
        exclude: [/bootstrap-sass-official/, /bootstrap.js/, '/json3/', '/es5-shim/', /bootstrap.css/, /font-awesome.css/ ]
      }
    },

    // Renames files for browser caching purposes
    rev: {
      dist: {
        files: {
          src: [
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/{,*/}*.js',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/{,*/}*.css',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/assets/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/assets/fonts/*'
          ]
        }
      }
    },

    // Reads HTML for usemin blocks to enable smart builds that automatically
    // concat, minify and revision files. Creates configurations in memory so
    // additional tasks can operate on them
    useminPrepare: {
      html: ['<%= yeoman.client %>/index.html'],
      options: {
        dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public'
      }
    },

    // Performs rewrites based on rev and the useminPrepare configuration
    usemin: {
      html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/{,*/}*.html'],
      css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/{,*/}*.css'],
      js: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/{,*/}*.js'],
      options: {
        assetsDirs: [
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public',
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/assets/images'
        ],
        // This is so we update image references in our ng-templates
        patterns: {
          js: [
            [/(assets\/images\/.*?\.(?:gif|jpeg|jpg|png|webp|svg))/gm, 'Update the JS to reference our revved images']
          ],
          css: [
            [/(assets\/images\/.*?\.(?:gif|jpeg|jpg|png|webp|svg))/gm, 'Update the JS to reference our revved images']
          ]
        }
      }
    },

    // The following *-min tasks produce minified files in the dist folder
    imagemin: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.client %>/assets/images',
          src: '{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif}',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/assets/images'
        }]
      }
    },

    svgmin: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.client %>/assets/images',
          src: '{,*/}*.svg',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/assets/images'
        }]
      }
    },

    // Allow the use of non-minsafe AngularJS files. Automatically makes it
    // minsafe compatible so Uglify does not destroy the ng references
    ngAnnotate: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/concat',
          src: '*/**.js',
          dest: '.tmp/concat'
        }]
      }
    },

    uglify: {
      options: {
        mangle: false
      },
    },

    cssmin: {

    },

    // Package all the html partials into a single javascript payload
    ngtemplates: {
      options: {
        // This should be the name of your apps angular module
        module: 'tracker2App',
        htmlmin: {
          collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
          collapseWhitespace: true,
          removeAttributeQuotes: true,
          removeEmptyAttributes: true,
          removeRedundantAttributes: true,
          removeScriptTypeAttributes: true,
          removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true
        },
        usemin: 'app/app.js'
      },
      main: {
        cwd: '<%= yeoman.client %>',
        src: ['{app,components}/**/*.html'],
        dest: '.tmp/templates.js'
      },
      tmp: {
        cwd: '.tmp',
        src: ['{app,components}/**/*.html'],
        dest: '.tmp/tmp-templates.js'
      }
    },

    // Replace Google CDN references
    cdnify: {
      dist: {
        html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/*.html']
      }
    },

    // Copies remaining files to places other tasks can use
    copy: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          dot: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.client %>',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public',
          src: [
            '*.{ico,png,txt}',
            '.htaccess',
            'bower_components/**/*',
            'assets/images/{,*/}*.{webp}',
            'assets/fonts/**/*',
            'index.html'
          ]
        }, {
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/images',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/public/assets/images',
          src: ['generated/*']
        }, {
          expand: true,
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
          src: [
            'package.json',
            'server/**/*'
          ]
        }]
      },
      styles: {
        expand: true,
        cwd: '<%= yeoman.client %>',
        dest: '.tmp/',
        src: ['{app,components}/**/*.css']
      }
    },

    buildcontrol: {
      options: {
        dir: 'dist',
        commit: true,
        push: true,
        connectCommits: false,
        message: 'Built %sourceName% from commit %sourceCommit% on branch %sourceBranch%'
      },
      heroku: {
        options: {
          remote: 'heroku',
          branch: 'master'
        }
      },
      openshift: {
        options: {
          remote: 'openshift',
          branch: 'master'
        }
      }
    },

    // Run some tasks in parallel to speed up the build process
    concurrent: {
      server: [
        'sass',
      ],
      test: [
        'sass',
      ],
      debug: {
        tasks: [
          'nodemon',
          'node-inspector'
        ],
        options: {
          logConcurrentOutput: true
        }
      },
      dist: [
        'sass',
        'imagemin',
        'svgmin'
      ]
    },

    // Test settings
    karma: {
      unit: {
        configFile: 'karma.conf.js',
        singleRun: true
      }
    },

    mochaTest: {
      options: {
        reporter: 'spec'
      },
      src: ['server/**/*.spec.js']
    },

    protractor: {
      options: {
        configFile: 'protractor.conf.js'
      },
      chrome: {
        options: {
          args: {
            browser: 'chrome'
          }
        }
      }
    },

    env: {
      test: {
        NODE_ENV: 'test'
      },
      prod: {
        NODE_ENV: 'production'
      },
      all: localConfig
    },

    // Compiles Sass to CSS
    sass: {
      server: {
        options: {
          loadPath: [
            '<%= yeoman.client %>/bower_components',
            '<%= yeoman.client %>/app',
            '<%= yeoman.client %>/components'
          ],
          compass: false
        },
        files: {
          '.tmp/app/app.css' : '<%= yeoman.client %>/app/app.scss'
        }
      }
    },

    injector: {
      options: {

      },
      // Inject application script files into index.html (doesn't include bower)
      scripts: {
        options: {
          transform: function(filePath) {
            filePath = filePath.replace('/client/', '');
            filePath = filePath.replace('/.tmp/', '');
            return '<script src="' + filePath + '"></script>';
          },
          starttag: '<!-- injector:js -->',
          endtag: '<!-- endinjector -->'
        },
        files: {
          '<%= yeoman.client %>/index.html': [
              ['{.tmp,<%= yeoman.client %>}/{app,components}/**/*.js',
               '!{.tmp,<%= yeoman.client %>}/app/app.js',
               '!{.tmp,<%= yeoman.client %>}/{app,components}/**/*.spec.js',
               '!{.tmp,<%= yeoman.client %>}/{app,components}/**/*.mock.js']
            ]
        }
      },

      // Inject component scss into app.scss
      sass: {
        options: {
          transform: function(filePath) {
            filePath = filePath.replace('/client/app/', '');
            filePath = filePath.replace('/client/components/', '');
            return '@import \'' + filePath + '\';';
          },
          starttag: '// injector',
          endtag: '// endinjector'
        },
        files: {
          '<%= yeoman.client %>/app/app.scss': [
            '<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components}/**/*.{scss,sass}',
            '!<%= yeoman.client %>/app/app.{scss,sass}'
          ]
        }
      },

      // Inject component css into index.html
      css: {
        options: {
          transform: function(filePath) {
            filePath = filePath.replace('/client/', '');
            filePath = filePath.replace('/.tmp/', '');
            return '<link rel="stylesheet" href="' + filePath + '">';
          },
          starttag: '<!-- injector:css -->',
          endtag: '<!-- endinjector -->'
        },
        files: {
          '<%= yeoman.client %>/index.html': [
            '<%= yeoman.client %>/{app,components}/**/*.css'
          ]
        }
      }
    },
  });

  // Used for delaying livereload until after server has restarted
  grunt.registerTask('wait', function () {
    grunt.log.ok('Waiting for server reload...');

    var done = this.async();

    setTimeout(function () {
      grunt.log.writeln('Done waiting!');
      done();
    }, 1500);
  });

  grunt.registerTask('express-keepalive', 'Keep grunt running', function() {
    this.async();
  });

  grunt.registerTask('serve', function (target) {
    if (target === 'dist') {
      //return grunt.task.run(['build', 'env:all', 'env:prod', 'express:prod', 'wait', 'open', 'express-keepalive']);
      return grunt.task.run(['env:all', 'env:prod', 'express:prod', 'wait', 'open', 'express-keepalive']);
    }

    if (target === 'debug') {
      return grunt.task.run([
        'clean:server',
        'env:all',
        'injector:sass',
        'concurrent:server',
        'injector',
        'wiredep',
        'autoprefixer',
        'concurrent:debug'
      ]);
    }

    grunt.task.run([
      'clean:server',
      'env:all',
      'injector:sass',
      'concurrent:server',
      'injector',
      'wiredep',
      'autoprefixer',
      'express:dev',
      'wait',
      'open',
      'watch'
    ]);
  });

  grunt.registerTask('server', function () {
    grunt.log.warn('The `server` task has been deprecated. Use `grunt serve` to start a server.');
    grunt.task.run(['serve']);
  });

  grunt.registerTask('test', function(target) {
    if (target === 'server') {
      return grunt.task.run([
        'env:all',
        'env:test',
        'mochaTest'
      ]);
    }

    else if (target === 'client') {
      return grunt.task.run([
        'clean:server',
        'env:all',
        'injector:sass',
        'concurrent:test',
        'injector',
        'autoprefixer',
        'karma'
      ]);
    }

    else if (target === 'e2e') {
      return grunt.task.run([
        'clean:server',
        'env:all',
        'env:test',
        'injector:sass',
        'concurrent:test',
        'injector',
        'wiredep',
        'autoprefixer',
        'express:dev',
        'protractor'
      ]);
    }

    else grunt.task.run([
      'test:server',
      'test:client'
    ]);
  });

  grunt.registerTask('build', [
    'clean:dist',
    'injector:sass',
    'concurrent:dist',
    'injector',
    'wiredep',
    'useminPrepare',
    'autoprefixer',
    'ngtemplates',
    'concat',
    'ngAnnotate',
    'copy:dist',
    'cdnify',
    'cssmin',
    'uglify',
    'rev',
    'usemin'
  ]);

  grunt.registerTask('default', [
    'newer:jshint',
    'test',
    'build'
  ]);
};
```

Comment: Do you have the same issue if you run `cd dist && forever start server/app.js` instead?

Comment: Doing this works as expected. Thanks for the suggestion! Now I wonder why this makes a difference.  Clearly you had a suspicion - what was it?

Comment: Before you gave this comment, I did the following with a gruntstart.js file with the following: var exec = require('child_process').exec;

exec('grunt serve:dist > grunt.log',
    function (error, stdout, stderr) {
        console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
        console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
        if (error !== null) {
           console.log('exec error: ' + error);
        }
}); And then doing: 'forever start startgrunt.js' which also works.

Comment: Now I am even more confused.

Comment: 1. I tried what you suggested before - and now that doesn't work - so perhaps I didn't test properly the first time.

Comment: 2. cd dist. and then 'forever start server/app.js' runs but the google login fails.

Comment: 3. cd dist/server. and then 'forever start app.js' does not serve the site. and so I only see '502 Bad Gateway' -- so clearly something is strangely dependent on the path??

Comment: Assuming you used a generator, or really express in general, it sets up application paths based on where you run the `app.js` from. The grunt command should handle it properly. However, when you run `forever start dist/server/app.js` you change the `app_path` to something different which could cause errors. So my suggestion is to understand what your paths *need* and make sure you run the express server respecting those needs.

Comment: Thanks -- looking into it... and will setup the forever env properly and test further!  This will be great to nail down, since others will have run into this as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much consideration, I finally discovered the answer.  The crucial step was to add a

```
console.log(process.env);
```

in my app.js.  This allowed me to discover the difference in the env variables, which caused all the issues.  So for those that run into this, the env settings under grunt serve:dist are:

```
export NODE_ENV='production'
export DOMAIN='https://tracker.dynazu.com'
export FACEBOOK_ID='xxxxxxx'
export FACEBOOK_SECRET='xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
export GOOGLE_ID='xxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com'
export GOOGLE_SECRET='xxxxxxxxxxxxx'
export DEBUG=''
export PORT='9000'
forever start dist/server/app.js
```

and this is what is now in my startup.js file, and all is fine.  I dearly hope this helps another newbie like me.